# Is there anything I can do to similarly access my smartphone?

Tags: applications

I recently went to [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) for Google Chrome and found an interesting feature that is the ["Tab to Search" (Omnibox)](https://www.chromium.org/tab-to-search).

In short, typing a website address and pressing the  Tab  key performs the search directly on a specific site without the need to change the search engine and other solutions.

The image below best illustrates what I am saying:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Following the example of [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) by pressing  Tab  and performing a search, the browser redirects me to the site search page, in this case ** https: //en.stackoverflow. with / research? q = term% 20search **.

Faced with this, I have a question

Is there anything I can do to similarly access my smartphone?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do the same thing with any browser on your Android phone.